What's the suitable tense here?

This building is old.
It is going to collapse or will collapse at any time.

I know that both are fine here but I have to choose one answer. I think that the better answer will be will collapse as there aren't clear signs of damage or visible evidence that make us predict that the building is going to collapse. It indicates that 'I think it will collapse because it is old.'
Am I right?

"is going to collapse at any time"

Or It may collapse at any time. Or could collapse.

Why is 'will' incorrect?

If you have to choose between 'will' and 'is going to', it's a bad test; neither is particularly natural. I would expect 'could'.

may, might, could, should, will, is going to: all are correct. Where is your research on this will/is going to? [I think the better answer is, not will be]

This question is similar to: humanity will die out vs humanity is going to die out. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"Will" versus "Going to"
OP enquired whether to use "will" or "going to" in the sentence:

This building is old. It is [going to collapse or will collapse] at any time.

Answer:
The correct choice is:

This building is old. It is going to collapse at any time.

Explanation:

"Going to collapse" implies a high likelihood of collapse, often based on present evidence or a sense of inevitability.
"Will collapse" is more neutral and suggests a future event without specifying when or why.
The phrase  "at any time"  strengthens the sense of imminence and inevitability, making  "going to collapse" the better fit.

The explanation given for using  "will collapse" is inconsistent with the phrase "at any time", as "at any time" implies the event is expected soon, aligning with the meaning of  "going to."
For further reference:

"Going to" is typically used when there is evidence or a strong indication in the present that an event will happen.


Learn more about "will" vs. "going to."*


No, will is fine too. -1

@Lambie Did you go through the link? I think you too can benefit from the link. Do you think people who set up these questions are jokers ? Your comments are nothing but confusing to the learners.

Thanks James for the clear explanation but I want to ask about something, if there isn't 'any time in the sentence ,can will be fine here or the existence of the word 'old' is an evidence that the building surely will collapse?

@OA Both "will" and "going to" can be used for an event that will happen in the future. To decide which is correct, you need to check for time expressions that indicate the timing or likelihood of the event.
Here, "at any time" is a time indicator suggesting the building is going to collapse very soon, making "going to" the better choice.

I got it, thanks.
